# ASP.NET MVC site menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When you create a ASP.NET MVC 2 web application in Visual Studio,  it gives you a default MVC site. It shows 2 menus [Home] and [About]. When you hover these menus it gives you this URL:

- [Home] localhost:1234/
- [About] localhost:1234/Home/About

Why is About under Home?

I want menu links like

- [Home] localhost:1234/
- [About] localhost:1234/About

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About is under Home because it's an action under the HomeController.

If you want to access about using /About, set up a new route in your Global.asax. Example:

```
routes.MapRoute("About", "About", new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few options here, you can either map routes individually as Darin and Alexn are showing, or you can do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Home", "{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = "" });
```

See how there's no controller defined in the path? This should mean you can just say `/About` or `/SomeOtherAction`. The limitation here is that it's going to match a lot of routes, and they'll all go to the home controller unless you add more specific routes above.

Answer (score 0):

You have two actions defined on the `Home` controller: `Index` and `About`. The Index action is defined as the default action for the site. For this reason `http://localhost:1234` resolves to `http://localhost:1234/Home/Index`. You could set a new route to accomplish this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "About",
    "About",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting about under any folder is a matter of personal choice.

If you would like to see the about file in a different folder structure the neat way of doing this in my opinion would be

1)Create a new folder in views called About.
2)Move the About.html file into this folder
3)Create a new file under Controllers folder called AboutController.cs
4) find the tag return View(); in the above created file and replace it with  return View("About");

If you would like to add more files under About section(eg:about-autor.html,about-fundinghouse.html) you could continue to add it in the about folder and make the necessary change in the controller to return the respective view.

Comment: this way i will need to follow this steps every time i will create a new menu?